# What exactly happened to GLaDOS after Portal?

Tags: video-games, portal, portal-2

The different games and additional material seem to have conflicting evidence:

In *Portal*,

> she seems totally destroyed but then *Still Alive* is played.

In *Portal 2*,

> it seems that she was merely shut down but she continuously says that Chell killed her.

Also, in *Lab Rats*,

> Doug says that GLaDOS died.

So did she

> die or not?

Comment: Is GLaDOS really alive? If so, and a backup can be made / restored - is that backup also alive? Finally, is the backup really the same as the original?

Comment: Did you not [listen to the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6ljFaKRTrI)?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The song wasn't completely honest.

Comment: @RogueJedi: well, I guess the cake is a lie.

Comment: Lab Rat is set after Portal but before Portal 2

Comment: That is not dead which can eternal lie, And with strange aeons even death may die

Answer (score 14):

She was shut down and disconnected from the world (hence she keeps claiming that Chell "murdered her"), but she wasn't completely offline

> She had a Black box memory that was replaying the last 2 minutes of her life. Again. And again. And again...

So in other words - no, she wasn't dead. It was much, much worse...

Comment: How did Rattmann know this?

Comment: So, she was dead in the sense which an organism without life signs which is subsequently revived is dead.

Comment: @RogueJedi It seems he doesn't - he thinks that GLaDOS is dead. Or he simply means that she is offline.

Comment: @Politank-Z I'd say that it was akin to clinical death, when heart stops beating but unconscious brain still lives on for a short time.